# ¿Cómo registrar un effect para agregar una nueva entidad en Angular Ngrx/Effects/Entity?

Tags: angular

Estoy usando @Ngrx/entity para almacenar mi data en mi store en Angular 8. El problema que tengo es en el efecto (effects), puesto que cuando llamo a mi primera acción CREAR_TIPO, todo funciona OK, ya que traigo la información de mi formulario. Esta primera acción me devuelve el payload que le enviaré a mi servicio (el objeto nuevo a crear). Sin embargo, cuando se ejecuta no me devuelve el objeto creado, dándome NULL, es decir crea el objeto en la base de datos, pero no lo regitra correctamente en mi store.

Llevo horas en esto, si pudieran ayudarme, este es mi código:

Este son mis acciones:

```
export class CreateTipo implements Action {
    readonly type = TiposActionsTypes.CREATE_TIPO;
    constructor(public payload: Tipo) {}
}

export class CreateTipoFail implements Action {
    readonly type = TiposActionsTypes.CREATE_TIPO_FAIL;
    constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export class CreateTipoSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = TiposActionsTypes.CREATE_TIPO_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: Tipo) {}
}
```

Estos son mis reducers:

```
case TiposActionsTypes.CREATE_TIPO_SUCCESS: {
            // console.log('action=');
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(action));
            // console.log('action.payload=');
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(action.payload));
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(action['paylaod']));
            return adapter.addOne(action.payload, state);
        }
```

Y, este es mi effect:

```
 @Effect()
    createTipo$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(tiposActions.TiposActionsTypes.CREATE_TIPO),
        map((action: tiposActions.CreateTipo) => {
            console.log('action.payload', action.payload);
            return action.payload;
        }),
        switchMap(tipo => {
                return this.tiposServices
                    .createTipo(tipo).pipe(
                        map(data => {
                            console.log('del efecto', data);
                            return new tiposActions.CreateTipoSuccess(data);
                        }),
                        catchError(err => of(new tiposActions.CreateTipoFail(err)))
                    );
            }
        )
    );
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para registrar una nueva entidad se requiere que el servicio devuelva la entidad creada, la cual será pasada al reducer el cual ejecutará la acción de incluir una nueva entidad al store.